# KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException

Tags: sql, ssis, timeout, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

We are using KingswaySoft SSIS integration to push data (60k) into CRM 2015. There is a daily job which is set to run this package, which passes successfully sometime and fails sometime with this error. Please suggest troubleshooting/fix.

> Delete Sales Transaction data of months in CRM:Error: An error occurred with the following error message:
>
> KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException: CRM service call returned an error: CRM service call returned an error: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:02:59.9843634. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.(Error Type / Reason: Timeout) (SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics CRM, v7.0.0.5660 - ISServerExec, v11.0.5058.0)
>
> KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException: CRM service call returned an error: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:02:59.9843634. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.(Error Type / Reason: Timeout)
>
> System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:02:59.9843634. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
>
> System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request to 'crm.abc.com.au/.../Organization.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:03:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
>
> System.Net.WebException(Status Reason: Timeout): The operation has timed out

Also since it is giving timeout issue, is it worth trying to increase timeout period? please guide how we can perform it.

Comment: You can try upping the timeout period in CRM.
 [Start here](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59bec3f4-4c5b-42b1-a436-d4c1f8fb7754/ms-crm-2011-exception-the-request-channel-timed-out-while-waiting-for-a-reply-after?forum=crmdevelopment)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we thank you for choosing KingswaySoft.

For the timeout error that you are getting, it indicates that a service call is taking a longer time than what you have specified in the connection manager. There are a couple of options in your case.

- If this is happening to a CRM destination component, you should
  consider decreasing its Batch Size setting.
- If you are using Upsert action with manually specified key fields in the destination component, you want to make sure you have created db indexes for the fields that you have selected for Upsert matching.
- You may also increase your CRM connection manager’s Timeout setting.

Based on the error message, it appears that you are using 180 seconds as your timeout setting, which is plenty for any service calls. Having a timeout error in this case could be an indication that you have some design issues with your CRM application. You might want to revisit your CRM plugin or workflow code if you have any.

Comment: I have almost same problem,When I use filters in Source Component,it works fine,but without using the filters,it always throw the error "CRM service call returned an error: SQL timeout expired.(Error Code: -2147204783",I am migrating data for Contacts Entity,Could you please help me to resolve this problem ?

Comment: @Sagar R Thank you for your comments. The SQL timeout expired error is a different one from the thread above.The SQL timeout expired error usually means that you have a long-running transaction which cannot finish timely on the server side and It is usually a sign that you either have a performance issue with your CRM database server, or there is a design problem with your custom code. There can be several different reasons for this error. Please see below:

Comment: @Sagar R a. You may have a plugin that runs complex queries (say aggregations), or you might be creating or updating a number of other CRM records. b. It may relate to the volume of data you have in the CRM system. In order to troubleshoot this issue, for CRM on-prem you may want to enable the SQL Server Profiler for your CRM database server to see if you can find anything related in the trace log. If you are using CRM online, it could be a bad design issue. You may want to raise a support ticket with CRM Support team to see if they can find anything.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response,I have resolved that problem by removing the "Order by" in Fetch XML,Yes you are right,This is the different thread,but unfortunately I was not able to find in SO regarding my concern,but found you guys in this thread so asked you the question,I guess we need more and more thread for such question which can get accurate response from your side.Again thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve the issue, we're happy to help! You're also free to reach out to us at any time by emailing us directly :)